# ¿Como agrupar datos de un DataFrame por varias columnas a la vez?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Estoy realizando un análisis de tiempos muertos de una línea de producción.
Tengo un DataFrame en formato CSV con las siguientes columnas:

```
'index', 'id_planta', 'fecha', 'linea', 'turno', 'Supervisor', 'CategoriaTM', 'CausaTM', 'duracionTM'
```

Solo la columna *duracionTM* tiene un valor numérico.

Utilizando pandas y quiero agrupar los datos por `CausaTM`. Una manera de hacerlo es:.

```
total_tm_linea16_prod_arranque_t1 = int(df['duracionTM'][df["linea"] == "P3 PREMEZCLAS"][df["turno"] == 'T1'][df["CategoriaTM"] == 'PRODUCCION'][df["CausaTM"] == 'ARRANQUE'].sum())
```

Sin embargo, no lo quiero hacer de esta manera ya que tendría que hacer una línea de código por cada causa y tengo muchas, además, el usuario puede crear causas nuevas y esto afectaría mi código. Lo que quiero es obtener un DataFrame donde obtenga el total de tiempo muerto de cada causa de las diferentes fechas que comprende mi archivo (en este paso, el archivo ya tiene solo las fechas que quiero trabajar).

El archivo csv. es:

```
index,id_planta,fecha,linea,turno,Supervisor,CategoriaTM,CausaTM,duracionTM
1,P3,01/10/2017,P3 EMB. AUTOMATICO 1,T1,CARLOS ROSAS,BODEGA DE CONGELACION,FALTA DE INGREDIENTE,55
2,P3,01/10/2017,P3 EMB. AUTOMATICO 1,T1,CARLOS ROSAS,PRODUCCION,ABASTECIMIENTO DE PRODUCTO A LA LINEA,32
3,P3,01/10/2017,P3 EMB. AUTOMATICO 1,T1,CARLOS ROSAS,PRODUCCION,ARRANQUE,40
4,P3,01/10/2017,P3 EMB. AUTOMATICO 1,T1,CARLOS ROSAS,PRODUCCION,CAMBIO DE PRODUCTO,65
5,P3,02/10/2017,P3 EMB. AUTOMATICO 1,T1,ANTONIO SANTAROSA,BODEGA DE CONGELACION,FALTA DE INGREDIENTE,20
6,P3,02/10/2017,P3 EMB. AUTOMATICO 1,T1,ANTONIO SANTAROSA,PRODUCCION,AJUSTE DE MAQUINA,10
7,P3,02/10/2017,P3 EMB. AUTOMATICO 1,T1,ANTONIO SANTAROSA,PRODUCCION,ARRANQUE,20
8,P3,02/10/2017,P3 EMB. AUTOMATICO 1,T1,ANTONIO SANTAROSA,PRODUCCION,CAMBIO DE PRODUCTO,30
9,P3,02/10/2017,P3 EMB. AUTOMATICO 1,T2,CARLOS ROSAS,BODEGA DE CONGELACION,FALTA DE INGREDIENTE,45
10,P3,02/10/2017,P3 EMB. AUTOMATICO 1,T2,CARLOS ROSAS,MANTENIMIENTO,CAMBIO DE TEFLONES,4
11,P3,02/10/2017,P3 EMB. AUTOMATICO 1,T2,CARLOS ROSAS,PRODUCCION,AJUSTE DE MAQUINA,38
12,P3,02/10/2017,P3 EMB. AUTOMATICO 1,T2,CARLOS ROSAS,PRODUCCION,CAMBIO DE PRODUCTO,45
```

La salida esperada (obtenida a través de una tabla dinámica de Excel es:

```
T1  
  BODEGA DE CONGELACION 
    FALTA DE INGREDIENTE    75
  PRODUCCION    
    ABASTECIMIENTO DE PRODUCTO A LA LINEA   32
    AJUSTE DE MAQUINA   10
    ARRANQUE    60
    CAMBIO DE PRODUCTO  95
T2  
  BODEGA DE CONGELACION 
    FALTA DE INGREDIENTE    45
  MANTENIMIENTO 
    CAMBIO DE TEFLONES  4
  PRODUCCION    
    AJUSTE DE MAQUINA   38
    CAMBIO DE PRODUCTO  45
```

Lo que hice fue sumar los tiempos de cada causa de las dos fechas que coinciden con los criterios *turno*, *categoriaTM* y *causaTM*.

Al tratar de agruparlos utilizo el código  siguiente:

```
df2 = df[(df["linea"] == "P3 EMB. AUTOMATICO 1") & (df["turno"] == "T1")]
df2.groupby('CausaTM').duracionTM.sum()
```

Sin embargo, la salida antes y después de `groupby` es la misma, es decir, no me suma las dos fechas.

Comment: Alejandro en estos casos siempre es bueno que agregues un pequeño ejemplo representativo del problema de tu DataFrame junto a la salida que querías obtener dado ese ejemplo. ¿Quieres agrupar solo por CausaTM y obtener la suma de duraciónTM para cada causa o quieres agrupar también por algunas de las otras columnas junto a CausaTM? La respuesta está en [pandas.DataFrame.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) en cualquier caso.

Comment: @FJSevilla, le agregué información adicional de acuerdo a tus comentarios. Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplemente debes agrupar por las tres columnas que quieres `turno`, `categoriaTM` y `causaTM` y aplicar `sum` sobre la columna `duracionTM`:

```
df2 = df.groupby(('turno', 'CategoriaTM','CausaTM')).duracionTM.sum()
```

El resultado será una serie, se puede convertir en un DataFrame con multiindex usando el método `pandas.Series.to_frame()`.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

datos = StringIO('''
index,id_planta,fecha,linea,turno,Supervisor,CategoriaTM,CausaTM,duracionTM
1,P3,01/10/2017,P3 EMB. AUTOMATICO 1,T1,CARLOS ROSAS,BODEGA DE CONGELACION,FALTA DE INGREDIENTE,55
2,P3,01/10/2017,P3 EMB. AUTOMATICO 1,T1,CARLOS ROSAS,PRODUCCION,ABASTECIMIENTO DE PRODUCTO A LA LINEA,32
3,P3,01/10/2017,P3 EMB. AUTOMATICO 1,T1,CARLOS ROSAS,PRODUCCION,ARRANQUE,40
4,P3,01/10/2017,P3 EMB. AUTOMATICO 1,T1,CARLOS ROSAS,PRODUCCION,CAMBIO DE PRODUCTO,65
5,P3,02/10/2017,P3 EMB. AUTOMATICO 1,T1,ANTONIO SANTAROSA,BODEGA DE CONGELACION,FALTA DE INGREDIENTE,20
6,P3,02/10/2017,P3 EMB. AUTOMATICO 1,T1,ANTONIO SANTAROSA,PRODUCCION,AJUSTE DE MAQUINA,10
7,P3,02/10/2017,P3 EMB. AUTOMATICO 1,T1,ANTONIO SANTAROSA,PRODUCCION,ARRANQUE,20
8,P3,02/10/2017,P3 EMB. AUTOMATICO 1,T1,ANTONIO SANTAROSA,PRODUCCION,CAMBIO DE PRODUCTO,30
9,P3,02/10/2017,P3 EMB. AUTOMATICO 1,T2,CARLOS ROSAS,BODEGA DE CONGELACION,FALTA DE INGREDIENTE,45
10,P3,02/10/2017,P3 EMB. AUTOMATICO 1,T2,CARLOS ROSAS,MANTENIMIENTO,CAMBIO DE TEFLONES,4
11,P3,02/10/2017,P3 EMB. AUTOMATICO 1,T2,CARLOS ROSAS,PRODUCCION,AJUSTE DE MAQUINA,38
12,P3,02/10/2017,P3 EMB. AUTOMATICO 1,T2,CARLOS ROSAS,PRODUCCION,CAMBIO DE PRODUCTO,45
''')

df = pd.read_csv(datos,  index_col="index")
df2 = df.groupby(('turno', 'CategoriaTM','CausaTM')).duracionTM.sum()
df2 = df2.to_frame()
```

La salida es:

```
>>> df3
                                                                   duracionTM
turno CategoriaTM           CausaTM                                          
T1    BODEGA DE CONGELACION FALTA DE INGREDIENTE                           75
      PRODUCCION            ABASTECIMIENTO DE PRODUCTO A LA LINEA          32
                            AJUSTE DE MAQUINA                              10
                            ARRANQUE                                       60
                            CAMBIO DE PRODUCTO                             95
T2    BODEGA DE CONGELACION FALTA DE INGREDIENTE                           45
      MANTENIMIENTO         CAMBIO DE TEFLONES                              4
      PRODUCCION            AJUSTE DE MAQUINA                              38
                            CAMBIO DE PRODUCTO                             45
```

---

**Edición:**

Para obtener una lista anidada en la que cada sublista contiene las columnas y el valor de la suma, del tipo `['T1', 'BODEGA DE CONGELACION',´FALTA DE INGREDIENTE´,'75']` se puede usar el método `to_dict` aplicado al retorno de `groupby`:

```
df2 = df.groupby(('turno', 'CategoriaTM','CausaTM')).duracionTM.sum()
lista = [list(key) + [str(value)] for key,  value in  df2.to_dict().items()]
```

**Salida:**

```
>>> lista
[['T1', 'BODEGA DE CONGELACION', 'FALTA DE INGREDIENTE', '75'],
 ['T1', 'PRODUCCION', 'ABASTECIMIENTO DE PRODUCTO A LA LINEA', '32'], 
 ['T1', 'PRODUCCION', 'AJUSTE DE MAQUINA', '10'],
 ['T1', 'PRODUCCION', 'ARRANQUE', '60'],
 ['T1', 'PRODUCCION', 'CAMBIO DE PRODUCTO', '95'],
 ['T2', 'BODEGA DE CONGELACION', 'FALTA DE INGREDIENTE', '45'],
 ['T2', 'MANTENIMIENTO', 'CAMBIO DE TEFLONES', '4'],
 ['T2', 'PRODUCCION', 'AJUSTE DE MAQUINA', '38'],
 ['T2', 'PRODUCCION', 'CAMBIO DE PRODUCTO', '45']]
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. ¿ puedo convertir el dataframe resultante en una lista de listas?

Comment: ¿Te refieres a algo así: `[[[75], [32, 10, 60, 65]]], [[45], [4], [38, 45]]]`?

Comment: no, quisiera que salieran todos los datos de las columnas más bien algo asi.  list =[['T1', 'BODEGA DE CONGELACION',´FALTA DE INGREDIENTE´,'75' ][...]]. La razón por la que quiero convertirlo a lista es porque quiero exportar los datos a un archivo Excel con formato utilizando el modulo xlwt y para colocar cada dato en la hoja de calculo utilizo un loop. si se puede hacer esto sin necesidad de convertirlo a listas me gustaría saber como se hace. gracias

Comment: @AlejandroGomez he editado la respuesta, mira al final de ella. Personalmente no he usado xlwt para trabajar con Excel, es posible que exista una mejor forma pero haría falta saber cual es la salida del Excel que deseas y que código usas ahora. De todas formas, no es difícil obtener la lista.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda